# Strange interaction with display:flex and rowspans in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-position, html-table

I was trying to `position: absolute` an element within a table, and found that for cells which span multiple rows, it would only reach the bottom of the first cell, and that this would only happen in IE. After some tinkering, it seemed the cause of this problem was that the table was nested in a div with `display: -ms-flexbox`, and removing this css meant the element could reach the bottom of the second row which the cell spanned.

Here is a JS Fiddle showing what I mean. In Chrome this would work correctly, in IE10, the green boxes aren't aligned to the base of the rowspan cell.

https://jsfiddle.net/LomLdtxg/8/

Can anyone explain how these two pieces of CSS interact, and why this happens? This seems to only be an IE explorer issue, is there some workaround / hack that needs to be done in order to have it render correctly?

Comment: Looks like an IE bug. Probably worth reporting it to MS. It's worth noting that the same effect occurs in IE11, even when using the standard `display:flex` syntax.

Comment: Also, just to confirm (since you didn't specify it; I hope you did try it though?) that Firefox works the same as Chrome, which also implies that it is an IE bug.

Comment: Awkwardly, I'm currently at the office and Firefox doesn't work with the proxy here. Intend to try it when I get home. For reference, works fine in Safari (though I guess that is still webkit

Comment: Yes, I'd expect Safari to work the same as Chrome -- although Chrome's Blink engine was forked from Wekbit last year and is by now quite significantly diverged it, so you should start considering them separately.

Comment: Can now confirm that it works in Firefox as well, so seems like it is only a problem in IE